# How to achieve this same effect in the dots being plotted using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am plotting a chart using ggplot2 in R. I have the same scatter-plot made using Excel and I really like the aesthetics of the dots plotted in Excel see image below).

[image: Scatter-plot in Microsoft Excel]

My ggplot2 codes currently stand as follows:

```
ggplot(mydata2, aes(TotalStay, TotalExpenses)) +  
    geom_point(shape = 19, position = position_jitter(width = 1, height = .5))
```

What do I need to add to my existing codes to get the same effect as the scatter-plot in Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a symbol that has a fill and a border color and specify both accordingly:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(2, runif(1e4)))
ggplot(df,aes(V1,V2)) + 
  geom_jitter(shape=21, width=1, height=.5, fill="#A1C0E5", color="#639DD2") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.